# Get the shipping method on a order

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping, sales-order

I want to get the shipping cost for a specific order on magento 2 v2.2.4. What is the query I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the shipping cost in the table `sales_order` in column `shipping_amount` and `base_shipping_amount`.
`shipping_amount` is in the currency in which the order was placed and `base_shipping_amount` is in the base currency.
THere are other fields that contain the `shipping` text. Their purpose should be self explanatory.
For example `shipping_invoiced` contains the shipping cost that was invoiced.
The same rule applies. All fields that start with `base_` represent amounts in the default currency.